# How to make multiple ajax call concurrently in redux-observable?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an array of string `schemaNames = [schemaName1, schemaName2 ...]`, for each element in the `schemaNames`, I want to make a restful call, to get the `schema`, and I want to get the result as an object.

I come up a way like this

```
export const fetchSchemasEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_SCHEMAS.REQUEST)
    .map(action => action.schemaNames)
    .switchMap(schemaNames => forkJoin(schemaNames
      .map(schemaName => ajax.getJSON('The API')))
      .map(doFetchSchemasFulfilled));
```

But it seems that this epic will return an unordered array so that I cannot specify the correspond between schemaName and schema. Could any one help me with that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
export const fetchSchemasEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_SCHEMAS.REQUEST)
    .map(action => action.schemaNames)
    .distinctUntilChanged((old, cur) =>
      old.length === cur.length &&
      old.every((v, i) => v === cur[i]))
    .switchMap(schemaNames => forkJoin(schemaNames
      .map(schemaName => ajax.getJSON(`RESR API`)
        .map((res) => {
          const ret = {};
          ret[schemaName] = res;
          return ret;
        })
        .catch(() => ({}))))
      .map(schemas => Object.assign({}, ...schemas))
      .map(doFetchSchemasFulfilled));
```